# Simple Traefik reverse proxy configuration

Tags: traefik

I'm starting up Traefik version 2.1.4 with the following configuration:

```
defaultEntryPoints:
  - http

entryPoints:
  hole-1:
    address: ':663'

frontends:
  hole-frontend-1:
    backend: hole-backend-1
    entrypoints:
      - hole-1

backends:
  hole-backend-1:
    servers:
      hole-server-1:
        url: 'http://11.23.24.1:3000'
        weight: 10
```

When I hit the `http://11.23.24.1:663` I'm hit with the Traefik page `404 pages not found`. When I go to `http://11.23.24.1:3000` in the browser, it works, it displays the page.

I can't seem to figure out how to set up a reverse proxy in Traefik to point `http://11.23.24.1:663` to `http://11.23.24.1:3000`.

I tried this, but I get the error

> 2020/02/18 11:39:43 command traefik.exe error: no valid configuration found in file: C:\config\traefik.yaml

```
http:
  routers:
    hole-router-1:
      rule: "Host(`11.23.24.1`) && PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service: hole-service

services:
  hole-service:
    loadBalancer:
      servers:
        - url: http://11.23.24.1:3000
```

Comment: traefik v2+ does not support frontends and backends. You can have a look here: https://docs.traefik.io/migration/v1-to-v2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\config\traefik\traefik.yaml`:

```
entryPoints:
  hole-1:
    address: ":661"

providers:
  file:
    filename: C:\config\traefik\dynamic.yaml
```

`C:\config\traefik\dynamic.yaml`:

```
http:
  routers:
    hole-router-1:
      rule: "Path(`/`)"
      entryPoints:
        - hole-1
      service: hole-service

  services:
    hole-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://10.23.24.10:3000
```

I started Traefik with: `traefik.exe --configFile=C:/config/traefik/traefik.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Traefik 2.1 do not support frontend and backends any more.
This repository provides some examples to deploy Traefik 2.1 https://github.com/wshihadeh/traefik_v2

Example to do it with Docker:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:

services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.http.address=:80'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("local.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    ports:
      - '663:80'
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik

   hole-backend:
    image:  hole-backend:demo-v1
    command: 'web'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.hole.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
        - traefik.http.routers.hole.rule=Host(`hole.local.me`)
        - traefik.http.routers.hole.service=blog
        - traefik.http.routers.hole.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
```

Comment: Could you post the exact example I have written as a v2? I'd accept then because I can't for saving my life get it right I keep getting: `2020/02/18 11:39:43 command traefik.exe error: no valid configuration found in file: C:\config\traefik.yaml`. I've read the docs, I just donät understand it.

Comment: @KarlMorrison please have a look at here: https://docs.traefik.io/providers/file/ Probably you are missing this part: `providers:
  file:
    filename: dynamic_conf.yml`

Comment: @Al-waleedShihadeh I see, however this isn't a simple example as was my question, I guess people who use docker will find your answer useful though.

Comment: The error that you get indicates that you have a syntax error, you can enable the debug log to see exactly the root cause of the error